# git, delete branch when is merge only to main

Tags: github

Is there a way to delete a branch when is merged to `main`?

If my branch is merged to another one it should not be deleted.

The info that I found is related to:

https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/configuring-pull-request-merges/managing-the-automatic-deletion-of-branches

But I need a way to do it just when is merged to `main`